# How to test redux API with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, redux

I am new to both `nodejs` and `redux`. I already have `node v7.10` installed on my machine. When I read the [redux doc](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Store.html), it claims I should be able to test the action, reducer and store API without UI.

So what I want to do is try to test them in a pure `nodejs` program.

Here are the step, I am trying to do:

1. create my testing directory for my testing project and run `npm init` to create a package.json file
2. run `npm install --save redux` to get redux module in my testing directory
3. create a file named `reducer.js` with the following content:

   ```
   import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
   console.log('testing.');
   ```

However, when I try to test my script: `node reducer.js`, I encountered `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:427:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:151:9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is written in ES6. Node doesn't support ES6 import feature. you can use babel to convert to ES5. you can use webpack to do this conversion or you can use [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-node7)